# Pancakeswap API (Subgraph)

Tags: graphql

I need help with syrup pool data fetching from pancakeswap subgraph api using GraphQL.
I tried to get smartchefs where the earnedToken in "PancakeSwap Token", the same way it is on the website, however the query result does not seem to give me any data.
The filtering of getting SmartChefs is not working (or I don't know how to perform filtering).
I am interested in TvL and cake rewards APY for the Cake single stake pool specifically.

If someone managed to fetch this type of data, it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

smartChefs retrieves data for SmartChefs.
where: {earnedToken: "0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82"} filters the SmartChefs where the earnedToken is the Cake token address. You might need to double-check this address to ensure it's correct.
Within the smartChefs field selection, you can specify the specific fields you're interested in, such as tvl for Total Value Locked and apy for APY.
Make sure to replace "0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82" with the correct address of the Cake token. Also, note that the data returned by the subgraph might vary based on what's indexed by the PancakeSwap subgraph.

You can test this query using the GraphiQL interface provided by PancakeSwap or any other GraphQL client. Adjust the query as needed based on the actual data structure returned by the subgraph.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).